# Angular script won't run when first loaded

Tags: angularjs

On page load the console log prints but the toggleClass/click won't work I even use angular.element but it has the same result.I need to change state in order for the toggleClass to work.I dunno what's wrong in my code.

```js
    .run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        console.log('test');//this prints test and it's ok       

 //this part won't load at the first loading of page.
                $('.toggle-mobile').click(function(){
                    $('.menu-mobile').toggle();
                    $(this).toggleClass('toggle-click');
                });
    //....
   }])
```

even doing it this way doesn't work.

```js
            $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {

                angular.element('.toggle-mobile').on('click', function (event) {
                    angular.element(this).toggleClass('toggle-click');
                    angular.element('.menu-mobile').toggle();
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

            });
```

Comment: Turning it into a directive works.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular way to render items is different from "On DOM Ready" that is why we need to treat these as 2 separate things.

Angular could render items later on even after DOM is ready, this could happen for example if there is an AJAX call(`$http.get`) and that is why a directive may be the recommended approach.

Try something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div toggle-Me="" class="toggle-mobile"> Sample <div class="menu-mobile">Sample 2</div>
  </div>

<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]);

myApp.directive("toggleMe", function() {
    return {
            restrict: "A", //A - means attribute
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
              $(element).click(function(){
                $('.menu-mobile').toggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('toggle-click');
             });
            }
        };
});

...
```

By declaring the directive `myApp.directive("toggleMe",...` as an attribute `toggle-Me=""` every time angular generates the input element it will execute the link function in the directive.

> **Disclaimer:** Since the post lacks from a sample html I made up something to give an idea how to implement the solution but of course the suggested html is not part of the solution.

Comment: @gabmon I added more details to explain, hope it helps

Comment: Directives work to this thanks.I already turn it into directive a minute before this answer came.

Comment: You can just use the class as it is. http://plnkr.co/edit/dCRJ0aMYBcnpFeiCotas?p=preview